# UI Block in angular 2

Tags: angular

I was used to of using [angular-block-ui](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui) for ui blocking in my angular 1 applications and found it to be very useful since it gives a lot of flexibility in blocking only some sections as well plus auto blocking the service (`$http calls`). This is their [demo](http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/#!/examples/element-blocking-examples) link.

Is there a similar solution in `angular 2`? I've searched for it but all the top links are related to `angular 1` ui blockers.